# Problem network échoué

Tags: networking

[image: problem network]

```
walid@walid-MS-7680:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] Mot de passe de walid :             
  *-network DÉSACTIVÉ       
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:04:00.0
       nom logique: enp4s0
       version: 06
       numéro de série: 8c:89:a5:31:8d:de
       taille: 10Mbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt  10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI  duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       ressources: irq:16 portE/S:e000(taille=256) mémoire:d0004000-d0004fff mémoire:d0000000d0003fff
  *-network DÉSACTIVÉ
       description: Ethernet interface
       identifiant matériel: 3
       nom logique: enp0s29u1u4
       numéro de série: 26:e0:0d:be:43:64
       fonctionnalités: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=ZTE  CDC Ethernet Device link=no multicast=yes
```

Comment: Please solution

Comment: It is really important to describe your problem in order to receive relevant answers. That being said, can I assume you're having issues setting up a USB ZTE mobile modem?

Comment: Welcome to elementary OS Stack Exchange. Question and answer posted here should be in English. Please either translate this or create a new one, deleting this one.